# 'position: fixed' on button within a div hides the button

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, draggable

I am creating a kanban board React app using the draggable-dnd library. Draggable divs (or "tasks") are part of the application, and I want to add "X" buttons to remove those draggables upon clicking. These buttons appear with their proper functionality when I place them inside the Draggable's div. However I want to style them properly with them fixed in the top right corner. So I've tried to add `position:'fixed'` as well as `top` and `right` positions. But when this CSS is implemented, the buttons disappear. What's weirder is that when I drag the draggable, the buttons temporarily appear until the draggable is re-dropped. I've tried changing the z-index of the button to high numbers, as well as re wrapping the button in a div, but to no avail.

The general code behind the draggable:

```html
<Draggable>
 <div>
   <RemoveDraggableButton/>
 </div>
</Draggable>
```

And the button:

```js
class RemoveDraggableButton extends React.Component {
 ...

  render () {
    return (
        <button 
          onClick={this.handClick}
          style={{
                  position:'fixed',
                  top: 10,
                  right: 10,
                    }}>
          X
          </button>
    );
  };
}
```

The [GitHub](https://github.com/bfbarry/kanban-board)

Comment: perhaps you need to add z-index?

Comment: Do you want `position: absolute` instead?  `position: fixed` will be measured relative to the page, but `absolute` will be relative to the nearest parent that has `position` specified to something other than static.  If this is indeed the problem, you might see the buttons up in the top right of the page when you're not dragging things because your current style should put them 10px off the top/right of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you can try by providing each div which is a parent of `RemoveDraggableButton` CSS property of position: relative and to the draggable button as position: absolute. With this , the position of the button would be based on the parent element rather than window object

Comment: This is it. Just to clarify for my own understanding  - what do you mean by 'window object' in "the button would be based on the parent element rather than window object"?

Comment: I referred to window object as variable based on the complete screen